# Can I get JSON.NET 4.0.4 working on Windows Phone 7.1 Mango?

Tags: json.net, windows-phone-7.1

I know that it was mentioned JSON.NET will work on WP Mango 7.1 in 4.0.5, and to use 3.x for now, however this is not working for me as 4.x was... It's not handling deserialization the same way for some reason, so I'm wondering if there's a way that I can build 4.0.4 from source to work on 7.1 now, without getting the Deserialization error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'.
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here - [Moving to JSON.NET 4.0.3 broke my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780389/moving-to-json-net-4-0-3-broke-my-app)

Quick solution - change the dll reference from the SL build to SL3-wp

Comment: Problem if I use the SL3-wp dll is the deserialization doesn't seem to work properly... It's not handling null's the way it does in my other app which is using 4.x on MonoTouch...