# Deserializing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json

I know that this question has been asked ad nauseam, but the existing answers haven't been particularly helpful for me. The best is [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/), but I don't want to create an object, I want to create a Dictionary.

I serialize my data like so, and I want to deserialize to precisely the same data structure:

```
    public static string AugDictToJSON(Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> dict)
    {
        return string.Join(",", dict.Select(
            d => string.Format("{{ \"{0}\" : [ {1} ] }}", d.Key,
                string.Join(",", d.Value.Select(i => SubAugDictToJSON(i)).ToArray())
            )).ToArray());
    }

    public static string SubAugDictToJSON(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        return string.Join(",", dict.Select(
                d => string.Format("{{ \"{0}\" : \"{1}\" }}", d.Key, d.Value.ToString())
            ).ToArray());
    }
```

---

EDIT: Solution is the following (from accepted answer):

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>> JSONToAugDict(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>>(json);
}
```

Comment: If you're using v4.5, [`JsonValue.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue.parse.aspx) or its siblings might be close enough. (Not on 4.5 here, so I can't really test code.)

Comment: By the way, your serialisation code is incorrect. JSON doesn't allow for unquoted strings as keys.

Comment: `I wonder whether there might be a more elegant way`. Using linq doesn't make your way elegant.

Comment: But it does make it readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the NuGet package '[Newtonsoft.Json](http://nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)'.

This package is used by WebAPI for serialization / deserialization and is quite fast.  More information can be found here:  http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Alternatively, as an IDictionary:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: Ok, see my revised answer for deserializing to a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar using Json.NET for an application I was working on (Taken from my own question: [Deserializing json string into an object - Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10115151/218159))

**JSON**:

```
{
    "disclaimer": "This data is collected from various providers and provided free of charge for informational purposes only, with no guarantee whatsoever of accuracy, validity, availability or fitness for any purpose; use at your own risk. Other than that - have fun, and please share/watch/fork if you think data like this should be free!",
    "license": "Data collected from various providers with public-facing APIs; copyright may apply; not for resale; no warranties given.",
    "timestamp": 1334183999,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
                "AED": 3.6732,
                "AFN": 48.400002,
                "ALL": 106.669998,
             }
}
```

**Object that will hold the data:**

```
public class ExchangeData
{
    public string disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> rates { get; set; }
}
```

**To create the data structure:**

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(args.Result);
ExchangeData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeData>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Hope it helps!